# Redgate SQL Prompt - how to reformat all files in source control repo

Tags: sql-server, formatting, ssms, redgate, red-gate-sql-prompt

Redgate SQL Prompt has a great feature of being able to reformat any open sql query, however I've got a large schema source controlled in SQL Source Control, that has a real mix of standards that I would like to harmonise. It would be too much work to open every object and run SQL Prompts format on each.

How can I auto format my entire SQL Source Control repository using SQL Prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back [I blogged about how to achieve this](http://www.red-gate.com/blog/redgate-products/sql-formatting):

Note that it's probably better to script objects as CREATE and search/replace CREATE PROCEDURE to ALTER PROCEDURE to avoid losing permissions/extended properties.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for, but sounds like it should work. I'm guessing that there is no way to run format over the files in the repository folder

Comment: No, that's not possible. Are you hoping to automate this as a continuous process?

Comment: Shouldn't need to, but may have to do it across a number of different projects, so was hoping for a one click format if possible!

Comment: My "workaround" shouldn't be too many clicks. It's not ideal, but better than doing it object by object!

Comment: @DavidAtkinson, ability to automate (say from the command line) would be really good when inheriting large SQL code repository from legacy systems/company acquisition/merger. Also for in CI/CD.